# How to use Nested Map(objects) or List(strings) in terraform variables and Tfvars

Tags: terraform

I have a requirement to use nested Map(objects) or List(objects) for creation of multiple resources using for_each

Example Code I'm using to define variable:

```
variable "private_endpoints" {
  description = "list of private endpoints configurations"
  type = list(object({
    name                              = string
    location                          = string
    resource_group_name               = string
    private_service_connection_name   = string
    private_connection_resource_id    = string
    subresource_names                 = list(string)
    is_manual_connection              = bool
    private_connection_resource_alias = string
    private_dns_zone_groups = map(object({
      name                 = string
      private_dns_zone_ids = list(string)
    }))
  }))
  default = {
    "PVE" = {
      name                              = ""
      location                          = ""
      resource_group_name               = ""
      private_service_connection_name   = ""
      private_connection_resource_id    = ""
      subresource_names                 = ""
      is_manual_connection              = ""
      private_connection_resource_alias = ""
      private_dns_zone_groups = {
        name                 = ""
        private_dns_zone_ids = [""]
      }
    }
  }
```

Values I'm passing under terraform.tfvars be like

```
private_endpoints = {
  "PVE1" = {
    name                            = "xxxxxxxxxxxxx95be"
    location                        = "Central US"
    resource_group_name             = "xxxxxxxxx"
    private_service_connection_name = "xxxxxxxxx95bexxxxx"
    private_connection_resource_id  = "/subscriptions/xxxxxxxxxxxxx/resourceGroups/xxxxxxxxx/providers/Microsoft.Storage/storageAccounts/xxxxxxxxx95be"
    # private_connection_resource_alias = null
    is_manual_connection = false
    subresource_names    = ["blob"]
    private_dns_zone_groups = {
      name                 = "mycomp.blob.core.windows.net"
      private_dns_zone_ids = "/subscriptions/xxxxxxxxxxxxxx/resourceGroups/xxxxxxxxxxxxx/providers/Microsoft.Network/privateDnsZones/privatelink.blob.core.windows.net"
    }
  },
  "PVE2" = {
    name                            = "xxxxxxxxxxxxxaa84xxxxx"
    location                        = "Central US"
    resource_group_name             = "xxxxxxxxx"
    private_service_connection_name = "xxxxxxxxxaa84xxxxx"
    private_connection_resource_id  = "/subscriptions/xxxxxxxxxxxxx/resourceGroups/xxxxxxxxx/providers/Microsoft.Storage/storageAccounts/xxxxxxxxxaa84"
    # private_connection_resource_alias = null
    is_manual_connection = false
    subresource_names    = ["blob"]
    private_dns_zone_groups = {
      name                 = "mycomp.blob.core.windows.net"
      private_dns_zone_ids = "/subscriptions/xxxxxxxxxxxxxx/resourceGroups/xxxxxxxxxxxxx/providers/Microsoft.Network/privateDnsZones/privatelink.blob.core.windows.net"
    }
  }
}
```

Calling these variables like below mentioned under main.tf

```
resource "azurerm_private_endpoint" "endpoint" {
  for_each            = var.private_endpoints
  name                = each.value.name
  location            = each.value.location
  resource_group_name = each.value.resource_group_name
  subnet_id           = module.lookup_subnet.id
  tags                = module.common_resource_tags.tags
  private_service_connection {
    name                              = each.value.private_service_connection_name
    private_connection_resource_id    = each.value.private_connection_resource_id
    subresource_names                 = each.value.subresource_names
    is_manual_connection              = each.value.is_manual_connection
    private_connection_resource_alias = each.value.private_connection_resource_alias
  }
  private_dns_zone_group {
    name                 = each.value.private_dns_zone_groups.name
    private_dns_zone_ids = [each.value.private_dns_zone_groups.private_dns_zone_ids]
  }
}
```

Error we are getting is like below mentioned:

```
│ Error: Invalid value for input variable
│
│   on terraform.tfvars line 1:
│    1: private_endpoints = {
```

I tried changing the Default and deleting it, as the error is with the terraform.tfvars I'm not able to find what needs to be changed.

The same code is working well if we are not passing multiple values using the same variable and terraform.tfvars. Issue is with the multiple endpoints data i'm passing from the terraform.tfvars.

Comment: You've only shared part of the error message. Please edit your question to include the entire error message, including the paragraph of text which explains how the value is invalid.

Answer (score 0):

In Terraform, you can use nested maps (objects) or lists (strings) in variables and tfvars files to provide structured data for your infrastructure configurations. This can be useful for passing complex data structures to your modules or resources. Here's how you can use them:

**### Nested Maps (Objects):**

Let's say you want to pass a nested map as a variable to your Terraform module. You can define the variable in your module like this:

```
variable "nested_map" {
  type = map(object({
    key1 = string
    key2 = string
  }))
}
```

**In your tfvars file (e.g., `variables.tfvars`), you can provide the nested map data:**

```
nested_map = {
  item1 = {
    key1 = "value1"
    key2 = "value2"
  }
  item2 = {
    key1 = "value3"
    key2 = "value4"
  }
}
```

**### Lists (Strings):**

If you want to pass a list of strings as a variable, you can define the variable like this:

```
variable "string_list" {
  type = list(string)
}
```

**In your tfvars file, you can provide the list of strings:**

```
string_list = ["item1", "item2", "item3"]
```

**### Using the Variables in Your Module:**

Now that you have defined your variables, you can use them within your Terraform module or resource configurations. For example:

```
module "example" {
  source = "./modules/example"
  nested_map = var.nested_map
  string_list = var.string_list
}
```

Inside your module, you can access the values using `var.nested_map` and `var.string_list`.

**### Using the Variables in Your Module Configurations:**

Here's how you can access the values of these variables within your module's configurations:

```
**# Accessing nested map values**
locals {
  item1_key1 = var.nested_map["item1"]["key1"]
  item2_key2 = var.nested_map["item2"]["key2"]
}

**# Accessing list values**
locals {
  first_item = var.string_list[0]
  second_item = var.string_list[1]
}
```

You can now use these `locals` values in your resource or module configurations.

Make sure to run `terraform init` and `terraform apply` after creating your configurations and tfvars files to apply the changes to your infrastructure.

Answer (score 0):

First, you defined your variable to be of type list, but then you are passing a map to it ([docs](https://developer.hashicorp.com/terraform/language/expressions/types#types)).

Second, you have defined your variable type as a map whose objects have a `private_connection_resource_alias` field, but you have it commented in the values you're passing to it, and that is wrong unless you explicitly mark the field as optional.

You probably want your variable to be declared something like this:

```
variable "private_endpoints" {
  description = "list of private endpoints configurations"
  type = map(object({
    name                              = string
    location                          = string
    resource_group_name               = string
    private_service_connection_name   = string
    private_connection_resource_id    = string
    subresource_names                 = list(string)
    is_manual_connection              = bool
    private_connection_resource_alias = optional(string)
    private_dns_zone_groups = map(object({
      name                 = string
      private_dns_zone_ids = list(string)
    }))
  }))
  default = {
    "PVE" = {
      name                              = ""
      location                          = ""
      resource_group_name               = ""
      private_service_connection_name   = ""
      private_connection_resource_id    = ""
      subresource_names                 = ""
      is_manual_connection              = ""
      private_connection_resource_alias = ""
      private_dns_zone_groups = {
        name                 = ""
        private_dns_zone_ids = [""]
      }
    }
  }
```

Moreover, I have the suspect that you misinterpreted the meaning of `default` ([docs](https://developer.hashicorp.com/terraform/language/values/variables#default-values)). With `default` you define the value it should be used when none is passed to the module, not the default value of each individual field, that could be done using the optional marker (e.g.`field = optional(string, "default_string_for_the_field")`, [docs](https://developer.hashicorp.com/terraform/language/expressions/type-constraints#optional-object-type-attributes)).